# How do I bind a value to a referenced custom content page (XAML)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-binding, xaml-binding

I created a custom ContentPage to show a circle avatar with initials. When I pass a value via binding it comes up as `null`, I debugged to check this. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

HomePage.xaml

```
<views:CircleView CircleText="{Binding Initials}"/>
```

CircleView.xaml

```
<Frame x:Name="circleFrame">
    <Label  x:Name="circleLabel"
            Text="{Binding CircleText}"/>
</Frame>
```

CircleView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CircleView : ContentView
{
    public CircleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CircleTextProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CircleText), typeof(string), typeof(CircleView), null);

    public string CircleText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CircleTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CircleTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the code below.

CircleView.xaml：

```
   <Frame x:Name="circleFrame">
        <Label  x:Name="circleLabel"/>
    </Frame>
```

CircleView.xaml.cs:

```
    public CircleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CircleTextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CircleText), typeof(string), typeof(CircleView), propertyChanged:(b,o,n)=>(b as CircleView).OnChanged());

    private void OnChanged()
    {
        circleLabel.Text = CircleText;
    }

    public string CircleText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CircleTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CircleTextProperty, value); }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
     <views:CircleView CircleText="{Binding Initials}"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initials = "Hello";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In CircleView.xaml, you should include a source to the binding, would be something like:

```
<ContentView x:Name="Self">
<Frame x:Name="circleFrame">
    <Label  x:Name="circleLabel"
            Text="{Binding source={x:reference Self}, Path=CircleText}"/>
</Frame>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: I just tried this, it does not work unfortunately :/

Comment: Is it possible to do `Source={x:Reference Self.BindingContext}` ?